# How to train for edge tpu on google cloud vision with object detection?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-automl, automl

When I try to export a model for the Google Coral, the option that should exist doesn't exist. As per this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/export-edge#edge-tpu), there should be an option to export for the Coral, but for me only TF Lite, Tensorflow.js and Container exist as options.

Answer (score 1):

The link you passed to the documentation [1] refers to image classification models (single label or multi-label classification). In the case of object detection  exporting to EdgeTPU [2] is not supported and there is no current workaround.

Thus, it is normal that you do not see the option.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/export-edge#edge-tpu

[2] https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/export-edge